# Tareas en segundo plano-Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

La pregunta en concreto es,  ¿si en xamarin forms se pueden ejecutar tareas en segundo plano o tiene que ser deforma nativa en cada plataforma?

Comment: Encontré esta publicación estoy intentando aplicarla, espero te pueda servir https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de qué es lo que quieres hacer. Como regla general, 
si tu tarea de segundo plano es de larga duración, deberás usar el mecanismo correspondiente a cada plataforma. Si es corta, puedes usar el estándar...

```
Task.Run(() => {
// tu código
});
```

.

Además, existen ciertos casos de uso típicos que tienen mecanismos especiales, por ejemplo la descarga en background de archivos. Para ese caso en particular existe un plugin ([HttpTransferTasks](https://github.com/aritchie/httptransfertasks)). Dependiendo de tu necesidad, puede que ya existe algún plugin. Te sugiero revisar [la lista de plugins oficiales de Xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents) y ver si tu requerimiento está cubierto.